# When does the warping of space time peak during the very early universe?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, spacetime

If gravity is a separate force and has taken its current form by 1 Plank time, then the very small 1 Plank length space-time must be warped beyond description according to General Relativity, or is it? Is it possible that space-time was strained by the General Relativity warping to beyond the point where it could return to a strain-free configuration, if the mass / energy source disappeared, and that this is what drove the expansion of space-time?

As space-time expands during the Grand Unification epoch, does the warping of space-time increase, or perhaps the warping of space time per unit volume, as the strain field has "room" (i.e., both the space and time) to fully develop?  If so, when does the peak space-time strain density occur? Could this explain the inflationary expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, one has to choose how to quantify "the warping of space-time". In general, it takes 20 numbers (independent components of the [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor)) at every point to specify how spacetime is warped!

A reasonable approach is to look at the [Ricci scalar curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature) $R$, which boils down this complexity into a single number. In a homogeneous and isotropic spacetime such as ours, it is just a function of cosmological time, $R(t)$, because it is the same at all points in space. Using the usual spatially-flat [Friedmann metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) for describing our universe, it is [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric#Curvature)

$$R(t)=6\left(\frac{\ddot{a}(t)}{a(t)}+\frac{\dot{a}(t)^2}{a(t)^2}\right)$$

where $a(t)$ is the Friedmann scale factor. So if we know how the scale factor evolves with time, we know how the scalar curvature evolves with time.

The evolution of the scale factor is complicated because in different eras different types of energy dominate in the universe. Let's simplify by looking at [three cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Useful_solutions) where only one type of energy dominates.

If the universe is filled with only matter, then

$$a\propto t^{2/3}.$$

Plugging this into the equation above gives

$$R=\frac{4}{3t^2},$$

so the curvature steadily decreases.

If the universe is filled with only radiation, then

$$a\propto t^{1/2}.$$

which gives

$$R=0,$$

so the curvature vanishes!

If the universe is filled with an inflaton field or dark energy, then

$$a\propto e^{Ht}$$

which gives

$$R=12H^2$$

which is a constant.

In none of these cases does the curvature ever increase with time.

So, without doing a more detailed analysis combining matter, radiation, and inflation or dark energy, we find that the warping is maximum at the Big Bang (it was infinite, according to classical General Relativity, when the universe was a point) and has been decreasing ever since as the universe has expanded.

Comment: I knew that quantification of warping of space-time was crucial. (I was thinking along the line of entropy.) I can see how there would be a single number for a specific space-time configuration / history, but does not space time warping vary locally (e.g., near a large mass concentration versus far away from any mass concentration)?

Comment: Yes, but cosmologists ignore those local variations in curvature in order to be able to have a reasonable model of the whole universe. Since on large scales there seem to be about the same number of galaxies in each cube, say, a billion light-years across, they treat the universe as if it were smooth and homogeneous rather than lumpy. This is sufficient to understand the overall large-scale dynamics. Then within that they look at how lumps evolve, such as galaxy formation or   variations in the CMB.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to understanding a gas, where one can talk about density, temperature, and pressure without having to track individual molecules. One averages over volumes containing *many* molecules.

Comment: In lumps like galaxies the curvature can increase. At the singularity inside a black hole, it has become infinite again, just like it was at the Big Bang. But the overall average curvature of the universe as a whole decreases as it expands.

Comment: Is it possible that for T > 0K, the space-time needs a certain amount of curvature, analogous to entropy, and that if curvature decreased below, then the space-time expansion slows, stops, reverses?

Comment: Of course, the warping will be infinite at the Big Bang, but I reject any singularity as reality. Let us think about the situation at 1 Plank time, when the space-time had size of ~1 Plank length.

Comment: *Is it possible...* Not in General Relativity. GR would allow the curvature to approach zero. For example, a $k=0$ universe with only.matter and radiation can do this. But our universe seems to have dark energy which means that, unless there are other cosmological dynamics we don’t know about, the curvature will approach a nonzero constant.

Comment: I’m also skeptical of singularities. Like many physicists, I suspect that an eventual theory of quantum gravity will be singularity-free. But for now we have no widely accepted theory of quantum gravity and classical GR with its singularities remains the consensus theory because of its many impressive successes.

Comment: I just fixed a terrible typo where I had accidentally written “never decrease” instead of “never increase”. I’m sorry if this confused you.

Comment: You and all the real physicists here will laugh, but I have an idea based on the "Fantastic Unification Postulate" where all forces are unified and produce a quantum at t=0. This FUP quantum then immediately decays into the "Duoverse" with size of 1 Plank length over the course of 1 Plank time, thus avoiding the Big Bang singularity. The duoverse also explains Dark Matter.

Comment: I don’t want to be dismissive, but there are lots of ideas about the pre-Planck-era universe and unfortunately no data (yet) to guide us. So personally I don’t think much about it, and on this site, which deals exclusively with mainstream physics, you may get negative reactions if you focus on this kind of thing. You are probably aware that personal theories are off-topic. You can ask about the kind of speculative theories that get published in respected physics journals, however. Is the FUP in this category? Where has it been published?

Comment: @FritzS *"when the space-time had size of ~1 Plank length."* In GR, the size of the universe is mathematically indeterminate at t=0. If the global curvature is <= 0 (which it very probably is), then the size of the universe is infinite for all t>0. So unless the curvature is positive, the universe never had a size of 1 Planck length.

Comment: @PM2Ring He probably “means” when the radius of curvature is on the order of a Planck length. (He hasn’t learned all this stuff yet.) BTW, why do you think $k$ is probably $-1$?

Comment: The FUP is unpublished personal theory. I will not mention it again, unless it gets published in respected physics journal.

Comment: As people explained in response to another question of yours, you can talk about your ideas like FUP in the chat rooms. The main one is the hbar. Whether anyone will engage depends on who is in there at the time and whether they find your ideas interesting.

Comment: BTW, a moderator will likely delete this discussion. We’re not supposed to use comments to converse.

Comment: I think $k$ is probably zero, since it does seem to be very close to zero. I wouldn't be surprised if it's actually slightly negative, though. And I wouldn't exactly mind if $k$ turned out to be slightly positive: that's what all the pop-sci books did when I was a kid. ;)

Comment: How do I get to "hbar"? I do not see this on any menu, or in the list of Stack Exchange communities.

Comment: Is there a Chat link at the bottom left of your page? Below Tour and Help?

Comment: Yes. I am an idiot.